# how to run java program in linuxmint os

Tags: linux

when i am going to run java code in terminal it show following error..

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.4-jdk
 * gcj-4.5-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

and when i am follow the instuctions i get following error

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main libice-dev i386 2:1.0.7-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
```

please help me.
    thank you

Answer (score 0):

first download jdk for linux then set path variable you may use following link to set path variable

"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893239/how-to-set-the-path-for-jdk-on-linux-2-6-33-r2"

then use sudo instruction 
to check if everything is perfect ,check version of java using java-version